# How to add icons in notification area?

Tags: windows-7

How to add icons in notification area?

Comment: What language / environment / framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class in WinForms, or call the [Shell_NotifyIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx) function in plain Win32.

**EDIT:** If you only want to implement a launcher for an installed application, there are [hordes of free programs](http://www.topshareware.com/system-tray-icon-manager/downloads/1.htm) out there that can help you.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write some code. Nothing too complicated, though. See the example in the first link I provided.

Comment: Can I make a notifyicon for a existed program such as  game.exe?

Comment: See my edited answer. Please consider asking non-programming questions to the fine folks on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) in the future, though :)